# Need to login to the Steam Community from within Steam?

Tags: steam

I remember I was able to browse things like my profile and others' profiles from the community tab in Steam. Lately, however, it seems that the community tab just shows me a page where I have to explicitly log-in with my Steam account name and password - even though I'm browsing from within the logged-in Steam client.

Is this normal? Is there anything I can do to make it authenticate automatically, or do I have to use the username and password manually?

Comment: I just checked and it logged me in automatically.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It happens now and then, especially when your Steam client has been running for a long time.

The built-in browser drops your session cookies, for some reason, making your current login invalid.

To solve this, either log-in or restart your client.

Comment: Restarting the client works and feels like the "correct" approach... thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is very annoying, but worked for me too.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old, but since some other people are probably going to google it anyways.

- You Either do what the other answers says (Log out-Log Inn or restart the client)
- Or go to your account details up in the right corner by clicking your name, and back to the site you had problem seeing because of the login screen.

Comment: Your answer doesn't even add anything new to the existing answers; only restating it. Also, going to your profile isn't going to refresh your login. (Well, it does half of the time, why is why simply refreshing the page in the browser works too... Sort of... It's more like hoping to trigger the login check.)